# Excel List with data from different columns and find result

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with data like below(sample):

[image]

The input i have is the Minor data ( i.e Minor1-1, Minor 3-5 etc).

I want all the Minor data from all 3 columns in a list box and if i select one, the respective Division and Subdivision should be displayed.

Something like below:

[image]

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So like this:

[image]

I used mid() and right to get the div and sub div.

The textsplit formula is:

```
TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,C1:C5,F1:F5,I1:I5),",",,TRUE)
```

based on my data.

Comment: Sorry! The data can be anything (not restricted to div, subdiv or Minor-x-y) just for sample i mentioned these.

Comment: Sorry, the methods shown work on the contents of the cells... While a bit of effort may be needed to redo mid() and right(0 or even other methods. As you clearly asked the data in those 3 columns ends up in the data validation list.